# IE10 Browser. jQuery Mobile will not change pages via javascript / IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, internet-explorer-10

I'm using jQuery Mobile.  I'm using JQM and javascript to change the page once I save data.  I want to change pages on successfully saving data to Parse.  Everything works fine in all browser and with Win7 / IE9.   Works everywhere EXCEPT  Win8/IE10.  With Win8/IE10, the the data gets saved to Parse.com, but the page change never happens.  the URL address changes, but the page displayed never changes.  here's my code:

```
      success: function(object) {
        $(".success").show();
        alert (" New Info Saved  ");
        //window.location.href = "#showFltInfo";   this works, seems to reload whole page though
                    window.location.hash = "#showFltInfo"; // this does same as above but doesn't seem to reload page, ie. it's faster
           //   this not work at all    $.mobile.changePage ($("#showFltInfo"));
```

Comment: Which version of jquery and jquery mobile are you using?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: Try `$.mobile.changePage("#showFltInfo");` without `$()` wrapping page id. And they should be stick together with no space between them. Here is an example http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/a55fq/

Comment: $.mobile.changePage('#showFltInfo', {transition: 'flip'});      This doesn't work at all.  Even though the JS successfully saved to parse and the "success was called, it did not change page in Win7 IE9.  I assume this wouldn't work in any browser either.  I don't know why it works in that Fiddle and not here.

Comment: Doesn't work in all browsers or only windows mobile?

Comment: Omar:   Thanks much for your help here.  OMG!  I finally found the problem.  I replaced the following:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script       and it works perfectly now.    works in all browsers I'm testing with.